# OData POST To Dynamics 365 Web API C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-365

I am trying to send a POST to the web api for Dynamics 365 using C#. However I am getting the error.

400 Bad Request

My content looks like this

```
{
  "new_account@odata.bind": "/accounts(4b6676f1-2c31-ea11-a810-000d3a23e249)",
  "new_name": "10012071567 - Fibre - ",
  "new_uprn": "10012071567"
}
```

The code is here

```
HttpRequestMessage request1 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/data/v9.1/entityname");
request1.Content = new StringContent(eoi.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
request1.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
HttpResponseMessage response2 = client.SendAsync(request1).Result;
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: What is the type of the object `eoi`? This *may* understand that `.ToString()` is intended to serialize as JSON, but it may not, in which case the base behaviour of returning `"Namespace.Type"` would be the default, and in this case decidedly incorrect.

Comment: Sorry I meant to day that eoi is a JObject

Comment: Did you intend to post to a path ending in `/entityname`? This doesn't look like it would be a valid resource name unless you have customisations to Dynamics 365, as per the [Web API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/reference/about?view=dataverse-latest) (n.b. note in the documentation: `Both Customer Engagement (on-premises) and Dataverse share the same Web API. The Web API documentation is available in the Power Apps documentation at: Use the Dataverse Web API.`)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and POST to

```
HttpRequestMessage request1 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "{yourorg}.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts(4b6676f1-2c31-ea11-a810-000d3a23e249)");
```